# How to control minimum and maxium values displayed on an Excel chart x-axis so that it chages itself automatically?

Tags: excel, charts

I am creating and excel chart that will graph the data I am receiving from a sensor. The data will be graphed for a 24-hour cycle before resetting itself. however the number of data points I will be collecting is massive and thus to display all data on a single chart may not be ideal. Thus I would like to create a chart that will only display points for a 1-hour window, and thus I will need a chart that will change its origin, and allow only a number of points to be  displayed. Is there any way to do this with the built in Excel chart controls?

Comment: Don't do this in the chart. Instead make a smaller subset of the data and chart that, then figure out how to have that smaller subset of data change to show only the data you want to see (which will be automatically shown in the chart since the chart just points to the range and shows what's there).

Answer (score 0):

When you create a chart it would automatically take the axis values as Auto. Which means this would assume a auto `Minimum` and `Maximum` point into itself. If it is not changed, go to Axis Options and change the Axis to Auto.